# Python threading requests json post

Tags: python, json, multithreading, request, multiprocessing

I try to do multithreading post requests to an api json, goes well some threads but shortly receive error from one of threads,

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

My code:

```
import threading
import requests
import json
import random

exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, key):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.key = key

    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        do_bet(self.name, self.key)
        print "Exiting " + self.name

def do_bet(threadName, key):
    while True:

        #do post on api

        def change_seed():
            payload = {'seed': random.randrange(100, 1000, 2)}
            requests.post('https://url.com/api?api_key=' + str(key), data=payload)

        def high(amount):
            payload = {'amount': amount, 'target': '90.00', 'condition': '<'}
            bet = requests.post('https://api.url.com/api?api_key=' + str(key), data=payload)
            win_bet = bet.json()['bet']['win']
            roll_bet = bet.json()['bet']['roll']
            return win_bet, roll_bet
        def low(amount):
            payload = {'amount': amount, 'target': '9.99', 'condition': '>'}
            bet = requests.post('https://api.url.com/api?api_key=' + str(key), data=payload)
            win_bet = bet.json()['bet']['win']
            roll_bet = bet.json()['bet']['roll']
            return win_bet, roll_bet

        def onloss(horl):
            if horl == 0:
                win, roll = low(100)
                if win == False:
                    change_seed()
                    win, roll = high(1000)
                    if win == False:
                        low(0)
            elif horl == 1:
                win, roll = high(100)
                if win == False:
                    change_seed()
                    win, roll = low(1000)
                    if win == False:
                        high(0)

        win, roll = high(10)
        if win == False:
            onloss(0)

        win, roll = low(10)
        if win == False:
            onloss(1)


# Create new threads
thread1 = myThread(1, "First", "8asd8a-hd7837hda-837g78-a37rjf3")
thread2 = myThread(2, "Two", "f56fah-sddddjf74f-kkkdj-fdbf446")

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

Does anyone have any idea how to make them work properly both in parallel?

Comment: Does this code work if you don't use any threads?

Comment: Pretty sure that threads have nothing to do with this. You're getting a non-JSON response from the API. Log the response and see what you're actually getting. Perhaps you're rate limited or some such.

Comment: With one thread works well, but there are two different accounts I want to do post request both of them.

Comment: Maybe not returning json because it is transmitted simultaneously on the same pipeline

Comment: @IsabelCariod Or because the site doesn't always return a JSON reponse, regardless of number of threads. You have got to verify it.